# Function throws error only on first call in a section

Tags: line-breaking

I'm setting up a template for my homework for this semester in LaTeX, and I'm getting an error that the first time I call a function it fails but every later time in the document it works. Here's the function:

```
\newcommand{\problem}[1]
{
   {
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}\\
        \noindent\large \bfseries Problem~#1
    }\\
}
```

and Here's a use( first fails second works):

```
\section*{Book Problems}
\problem{1.1.2b}
\problem{1.1.2c}
```

And here's all pdflatex says:

```
 ...                                              

l.48 \problem{1.1.2b}

?

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 48--60
```

I think it's related to the `\vspace`. Do you know of any ways to not let it fail?

Comment: That is a warning not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given enough code to be sure but

```
 \vspace{2\baselineskip}\\
```

would I expect give the "no line here to end" error if preceded by a blank line, and the underfull box  10000 warning if not.

It is always an error to use `\\` in vertical mode or at the end of a paragraph, so just delete it. (Possibly replace by `\par` *before* the `\vspace`)

Note that the second `\\` will also give a warning if the heading is followed by a blank line in the source

```
\problem{1.1.2b}

xxx
```

Even if used as

```
\problem{1.1.2b}
xxx
```

It is not a real heading so for example does not prevent a page break after the heading.

It is usually best to define such environments using `\newtheorem` so that the heading uses the usual latex heading (or list item) mechanisms and numbering will be automatic and  cross referencing with `\ref` is possible.